# how to pass variables from GDB to invoked python interpeter

Tags: python, gdb

From some version of GDB (I guess 7 or so) it is possible to invoke python from GDB in interactive or non interactive way.

Here is some example:

```
(gdb) python print("gdb".capitalize())
Gdb
(gdb)
```

Is it possible to pass variables from used in GDB into Python? I've tried something like this but with no luck:

Try to pass C variable named c_variable

```
(gdb) python print(c_variable.capitalize())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c_variable' is not defined
Error while executing Python code.
```

Try to pass GDB's variable named $1

```
(gdb) python print($1.capitalize())
  File "<string>", line 1
    print($1.capitalize())
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error while executing Python code.
```

**EDIT**

Almost imediatelly after my question I've found this question [passing c++ variables to python via gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256498/passing-c-variables-to-python-via-gdb)

So I've end up with following:

```
(gdb) whatis p_char
type = char *

(gdb) ptype p_char
type = char *

(gdb) p p_char
$1 = 0x8002004 "hello world"

(gdb) python x=str(gdb.parse_and_eval('p_char')); print(x.split(" "))
['0x8002004', '"hello', 'world"']
```

This is something that I can work with but I need to do some extra cleanup (remove quotes, address etc), is there any better way? And I still do not know if is possible to pass `$1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try to pass C variable named c_variable
> Try to pass GDB's variable named $1

```
py print(gdb.parse_and_eval("c_variable"))
py print(gdb.parse_and_eval("$1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with Python and GDB I would highly recommend reading [this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html).  Of special interest to you would be [this page that includes `parse_and_eval`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html#Basic-Python) as well as [this page on values](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html#Values-From-Inferior).

The `gdb.parse_and_eval` function returns a `gdb.Value` object.  For values that are strings you can use the `string` method, so:

```
(gdb) python print(gdb.parse_and_eval("string_var").string())
Hello World
(gdb) python print(gdb.parse_and_eval("string_var").string()[::-1])
dlroW olleH
```